# How can Tikzposter be used to create a poster with multiple pages?

Tags: posters, tikzposter

I'm trying to create a poster using Tikzposter with the following code:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter} % See Section 3
\input{Settings/Packages.tex}
\input{Settings/Administrative.tex}

\title{\myTitle} \institute{} % See Section 4.1
\author{Emanuel Enberg} \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[]{Files/MID_RGB.png}}
\usetheme{Autumn} % See Section 5
\usecolorstyle{Britain}

\renewcommand\thesection{}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{columns}


\column{0.37}% Width set relative to text width
\block{Abstract}{\input{Chapters/Sections/AbstractContents.tex}}
\block{Inledning}{\input{Chapters/Sections/Chapter1_Section1_Inledning.tex}}

\column{0.63}
\block{Syfte \& frågeställning}
{\input{Chapters/Sections/Chapter1_Section2_Syfte-och-fragestallningar.tex}}
\block{Bakgrund \& tidigare forskning}
{\input{Chapters/Sections/Chapter1_Section3_Bakgrund-och-tidigare-
forskning_Part1.tex}}

\begin{subcolumns}
    \subcolumn{0.465} 
    \block{Nervcell}{\input{Chapters/Sections/Subsections/Chapter1_Section3_Subsection1_Nervcell.tex}} 
    \block{Maskininlärning}{\input{Chapters/Sections/Subsections/Chapter1_Section3_Subsection2_Maskininlarning.tex}}

    \subcolumn{0.535} 
    \block{Vektorer \& matriser}{\input{Chapters/Sections/Subsections/Chapter1_Section3_Subsection3_Vektorer-och-matriser.tex}}
    \block{Artificiell neuron, del 1}{\input{Chapters/Sections/Subsections/Chapter1_Section3_Subsection4_Artificiell-neuron_Part1.tex}}
\end{subcolumns}

\end{columns}


%%%%%% HERE I WOULD NEED TO MAKE A NEW PAGE/POSTER


\end{document}
```

This code gives me the following output:

[image]

However, as you can see in the image, I can't fit all of the content on a single page. I figure I would need at least 3 pages in total.

So far I've tried using `\newpage` and placing more blocks after. However, that gives me with some nasty errors.

I have considered making separate documents for each page, but that would mean I can't reference figures and equations from other pages.

Is there any way to generate a poster with multiple pages using Tikzposter? If not, is there any other package with similar functionality to Tikzposter which would allow me to do so?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you planning to actually display **three** posters? If that is the case, you should consider to try and remove unnecessary content and reduce it such it fits in only one poster. The idea is not to include everything, but just enough information to convey your idea

Comment: The xr package will allow you to reference across separate documents.  You can't use \include, and \includeonly doesn't work on \input.

Comment: I recently played with this: beamerposter will allow you to add multiple frames aka poster pages but automatically repeat the poster header/title. the poster library from `tcolorbox' worked well - simply make multiple tcbposter pages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This shows how to use the xr package to link two tikzposters.  The tricky bit was making the equation numbers continuous.

First poster (test5.tex):

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{test6}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\newlabel{lasteq}{{\arabic{equation}}{\thepage}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\block{First page}{\begin{equation}\label{first}
x=a
\end{equation}
See equation (\ref{second})}
\end{document}
```

Second poster (test6.tex):

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{test5}
\AtBeginDocument{\setcounter{equation}{\getrefnumber{lasteq}}}
\begin{document}
\block{Second page}{\begin{equation}\label{second}
y=b
\end{equation}
See equation (\ref{first})}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there's not.

A `tikzposter` is basically a big `tikzpicture`, and that can't be broken across pages. Of course, multi-page posters doesn't make sense in the first place, so you should have less content, not more pages.

But you can have a look at `baposter` (http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/), which seems to allow for multiple `poster` environments, and thus multiple pages. Quick example:

```
\documentclass[a3paper]{baposter}
\usepackage{caption}

% set default options for poster(s)
\setkeys[ba]{posterbox}{
headerborder=closed,
headerColorOne=black!30,
headerColorTwo=black!50,
borderColor=blue
}
\setkeys[ba]{poster}{
bgColorOne=black!10,
bgColorTwo=black!20,
columns=2
}
\begin{document}
\begin{poster}{}
{}
{title}
{\textsc{Author}}
{}

\headerbox{Text}{name=text,column=0,row=0}{%
\captionof{figure}{Stuff \label{a}}
}
\end{poster}

\begin{poster}{
  headerheight=0pt % <- don't need space for title
}
{}
{}
{}
{}

\headerbox{Text}{name=text,column=0,row=0}{%
Ref to fig. \ref{a}
}
\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

[image: too much poster]